# PHP While loop not working but no errors

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, while-loop

Why my while loop not working, I also have a while loop on the other PHP page, but there's only one page that doesn't work with PHP's while loop. But it does not contain any errors. Here's my code:

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_accredited";
$result = $con->query($sqlquery);
$num = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($num <= 0){
    echo "<h2>No records found.</h2>";
}
$x=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $x++;
    echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$x.'</td>
                <td>'.$row['permitno'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['boarding_optr'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['boarding_addr'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['orno'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['boarding_name'].'</td>
            </tr>
    ';
}
```

Comment: `$num` will be an array when you run `$num = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` So your following IF is not doing what you think

Comment: You will also have lost the first result in your result set as you run that before starting the while loop

Comment: You should use `mysqli_num_rows` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: As well as a more robust testing process before releasing code to LIVE

Comment: As for debugging in general, try dumping your variable before loops and conditions to check if they are as expected

Comment: `$x = 0` and `$x++` why? At the end `$x == $num`!

Comment: @Karkouch Because the OP appears to want to output a number in col 1 of the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were reading your first result row and incorrectly using that as a count of resulted rows, then ignoring its content.

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_accredited";
$result = $con->query($sqlquery);
$num = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
// this reads the first row of your result set and then of course gets lost
//$num = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

// use mysqli_num_rows instead
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) <= 0){
      echo "<h2>No records found.</h2>";
} else {
    $x=0;

    // now this will get the first row, which you must have been missing before
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         $x++;
         echo '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$x.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['permitno'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['boarding_optr'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['boarding_addr'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['orno'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['boarding_name'].'</td>
                </tr>
          ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your reply! I was not able to fix my problem lastnight because I was so sleepy. But then I realised that I messed up. I didn't see it coming :D haha. BTW big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_accredited";
$result = $con->query($sqlquery);
$x=0;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $x++;
    echo '
      <tr>
      <td>'.$x.'</td>
      <td>'.$row['permitno'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['boarding_optr'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['boarding_addr'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['orno'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['boarding_name'].'</td>
      </tr>
    ';
  }
} 
else {
  echo "<h2>No records found.</h2>";
}
```

Comment: if $num is greater than 0 your while loop starts the same, try this

Comment: Add some description to help user to identify what was wrong and how your answer might help him/her.